# Can't get access to environment variables

Tags: kubernetes, dockerfile, vuejs3, vite

I can't get access to the environment variables. In import.meta.env.VITE_VAR1 or import.meta.env.VITE_BASE_URL get undefined. I attach a screenshot values.yaml and docker file below. The deployment  launched using a container in Kubernetes.

[dockerfile image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dOBKH.png)
[values.yaml file image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y284H.png)

How to get access to variables in dev and prod environments
if you need more information, ask me

Comment: If this is running in Kubernetes, one thing to try is to run `kubectl describe pod -n YourNamespaceHere YourPodNameHere`  That will tell what environment variables are actually on the container.   (It may be that they are not being set.)  You can get the pod name via this command `kubectl get pods -n YourNamespaceHere`

Comment: where is your docker compose file ?

Answer (score 0):

In your docker file use ARG and define a default var/s value/s, so

> ARG varname=varvalue

```
ARG VITE_VAR=true
ARG VITE_BASE_URL=https://domen1.com
```

If you have a docker compose afterwards, then remove the ARG lines from the docker file and add to docker compose file the variables as shown below:

```
services:
  [service-name]:
    image: [image-name]
      environment:
        - VITE_VAR="true"
        - VITE_BASE_URL="https://domen1.com"
```

In kubernetes you can do the same thing even get environment values set beforehand, refer to this [link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-environment-variable-container/)